# give a unique number from 1 to 200 for each row? assign a number for each row

Tags: php, mysql, row

I have this small code to display 200 rows and I want to give each row a number a per the no of votes. 
How can I do it?
This is what I thought of but it does not work.

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 200;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row = 1;
    echo $row++;
       echo $row['fullname'];
       echo '<br>';
    }
```

the output is making all row output to 1.

**edit :**
okay so some of the answers did the job but it does not work on the pagination. it counts from 1 on page 2,3,4,5.... heres the code.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result_per_page = 20;
$no_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$no_of_page = ceil($no_of_result/$result_per_page);


if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
   $page = 1;
}else{
   $page = $_GET['page'];
}

$page_first = ($page-1)*$result_per_page;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ' . $page_first . ',' . $result_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $num++;
   echo $row['fullname'];
   echo '<br>';
}

for($page=1;$page<=$no_of_page;$page++){
   echo '<a href="/?page='.$page.'">'.$page.'</a>';
   echo ' ';
}

?>
```

Comment: set `$number =1;` in above while loop and increment `$number++` before while loop closing bracket like `$number=1; while(logic){ echo $number; $number++;}`

Comment: You can't use the variable `$row` to hold both a counter and the result set returned from the database query. You'll need two different variables.

Comment: @Mark please check updated comments

Comment: @Mark you are now changing the fundamental base of your question. Don't do that.

Comment: @Mark mean on pagination 2 page it will start from 1 correct?

Comment: please share your full code your first page will show 200 records?

Comment: please update `$num = 1;` with `$num = $page * $result_per_page+ 1;` in above while loop

Comment: please update `$num = 1;` with `$num = $page * $result_per_page+ 1;` in above while loop

Answer (score 1):

Try to read your code line by line and see what it does.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { # > Set variable $row to the next result set or exit when there are none.                                   
  $row = 1;                                 #  Set variable $row to value 1. 
  echo $row++;                              #  Increment variable $row to + 1.
  echo $row['fullname'];                    #  Row is now an integer, not an array. (You did that 2 statements ago)
  echo '<br>';                              #
} // end of loop, start again --------------|
```

A solution would be:

```
$id = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  echo $id++;
  echo $row['fullname'];
  echo '<br>';
}
```

As for the page, you're overwriting the previous value:

```
for($s=$page;$s<=$no_of_page;$s++){
 echo '<a href="/?page='.$s.'">'.$s.'</a>';
 echo ' ';
}
```

Comment: hey it did work but it does not work on pagination. check the edit